# Solving for constants and initial conditions in differential equation with given solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the differential equation $y'' + ay' + by = 0$, and I've found that the solution is $y = 3e^{-x} + 2e^{2x}$.

However, I'm having trouble determining the constants $a$ and $b$, as well as the initial conditions for $x = 0$ that give just this solution.

Correct solution: $a = -1, b = -2$, and initial condition $y(0) = 5$ and $y'(0) = 1$.

Can someone help me understand how to arrive at this answer? I'm really struggling to understand the steps involved.

Plugging this solution into the differential equation, we get

$$\large(3e^{-x} + 2e^{2x})'' + a(3e^{-x} + 2e^{2x})' + b(3e^{-x} + 2e^{2x}) = 0$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I find the question a bit strange. Your first paragraph says:

> I'm trying to solve the differential equation $y'' + ay' + by = 0$, and I've found that the solution is $y = 3e^{-x} + 2e^{2x}$.

But I don't see how you can arrive at that *particular solution*, of that differential equation that depends on those apparently unknown parameters $a$ and $b$. We can *naively*  solve the differential equation and then go back to imposing conditions on $a$ and $b$ as follows.

- Solving the DE: $y''+ay'+by=0$ over a real domain:
  \begin{align*}
  y''+ay'+by&=0,\\
  (\lambda^{2}+a\lambda +b)e^{\lambda x}&=0,\quad y(x):= e^{\lambda x},\\
  \lambda_{1,2}&=-\frac{a}{2}\pm \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^{2}-4b}
  \end{align*}
  Then, *when $\lambda_{1}\not=\lambda_{2}$ and they are real eigenvalues*, we have a *general solution* of the form $y(x)=c_{1}e^{\lambda_{1}x}+c_{2}e^{\lambda_{2}x}$ for arbitrary constant $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$. Hence, the *general solution* for DE is give by
  $$y(x)=c_{1}e^{\left(-\frac{a}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^{2}-4b}\right)x}+c_{2}e^{\left(-\frac{a}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{a^{2}-4b} \right)x}$$
  Then, we can see the that a natural condition to be imposed *in this case* must be: $a^{2}-4b>0$.